# How long does sqlserver keep connections active after they are closed?

Tags: sql-server, connection

In a asp.net/Sqlserver project, we create connections using ado.net (sql authentication) and we see a behaviour where there  are  a lot of active connections in "sleeping","Awaiting  command" status

The  code does the following - Get a connection from common  function, update db, Commit transaction, close & dispose transaction,  close connection.

1) In  sqlserver 2008 when our program  runs for  sometime (it  updates the db every few secs), the  number of active connections increases dramatically and  sqlserver starts refusing new connections (as the default connections is 100)
2) In sqlserver 2005, we see that the connections are getting reused and  work fine.  Our max connections does not go above 15-20.

We found an issue from MSFT on 2008 and  conveyed to the client.
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=383517 - Talks about 2008 not releasing closed connections  immediately.

In the client place, we see the same issue in  sql2005 too.

My question,  is when the .net program calls close() on a connection, how long does sqlserver keeps it active ?

Thanks a lot for any hints

Regards
Anand

Comment: Can you post your offending code?

Answer (score 1):

Connections are going to the pool. If they are not reused from there, and the number of connections increases, you certainly did not clean them up properly. Make use of `using` blocks for any disposable type (also transactions, commands and whatever).

To clear the connection pool you can call this static method:

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

This should remove all connections and are *not used* in the pool. The others are still in use.